# Expo command is not found ubuntu

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development

I have installed expo with this command - `npm install expo-cli -g`
but when I am writing expo in command line, is writing that expo in not found.

I have tried to install with yarn and it was installed successful but is writing that expo in not found.

I have tried to export `PATH` to `~/.profile` but this did not help me.

What do I need to do to make my expo project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is installed, expo might not be in your `PATH`.

1. Check if npm global is in your path. `$ echo $PATH`,
2. if not in your path add npm global to your path.

get the path of your global npm `npm config get prefix`

add the output of the above command to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file.

```
# replace npm-global-path with the output of npm config get prefix
export PATH=npm-global-path/bin:$PATH
```

then

```
# source your .bashrc, .zshr or *.profile
source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.zshrc
```

[Environment variables in bash_profile or bashrc?](https://superuser.com/questions/409186/environment-variables-in-bash-profile-or-bashrc)

Comment: post the output of `npm config get prefix`?

Comment: /home/denis/.npm-global

Comment: run `ls /home/denis/.npm-global/bin`, and paste the output.

Comment: exp  expo  expo-cli

Comment: where did you export your path?

Comment: it should be something like `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

Comment: is it still not working? can you also share `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Try `npx expo init AwesomeProject`, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved with following steps

1. first of all install expo-cli using the below command line

   npm install expo-cli -g

2 after installation of expo-cli set global variable using below command line

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Happy Coding!